# SharePoint Online Custom List - Show Links based on a Selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

**Goal:**  Select a department from a "dropdown-type" list and then display links based on my selection.

I have this working now with HTML/JavaScript, but it's not on my SharePoint Online tenant.

I would like to convert this to a SharePoint list so that my end users can update easily vs. having them deal with HTML/JavaScript.

**Requirements**

1. I want to be able to ask the user to select a location.

- Site A
- Site B
- Site C
- Etc.

2. Based on the selection, display a list of links.

Is this possible via out of the box SharePoint Online lists/tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using a collection of custom views on a custom list that includes the URLs for each area and presented that view in it's own page. Lots of views & pages, but once the first one was done, it was just a copy and replace the text/variables for each new one as appropriate.

*A side note, the build the link list on the parent page, I used a Content Query web part from the PnP solutions and queried the list and wrote a custom template using handlebars to build a dropdown list. This presented a much more usable solution than just a long list of links.

Answer (score 1):

No, not exactly by out of the box SharePoint but you can easily customise the form by using PowrrApp customise form option.
You don't need to write a java script instead you will just enter excel type formula and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you plan to display the links, but it does not sound like something achievable with OOB solutions.
Here are a few workarounds might help:

1. PowerApps forms as @Namwar Rizvi suggests. Display the hyperlinks on different screens and configure redirection based on column values.

   Reference: [Conditional Navigation - Triggered by User Selection.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/News-Announcements/Conditional-Navigation-Triggered-by-User-Selection/ba-p/19488)
2. Calculated column to display different links based on the choice column value.
3. [Column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to give conditional view in a list, or return different URLs to another list of hyperlinks in a column.